# Equivalence classes of norms on $R^n$ under symmetries

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $G \leq {\bf GL}_n$ be a symmetry group on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For simplicity, we can consider the case $G = {\bf GL}_n$.

Define two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\| \cdot\|_2$ to be *equivalent under $G$* if there exists $A \in G$ such that

$ \ \forall \ x \ \| A x \|_1 = \| x\|_2$

It is trivial to show that this defines equivalence classes on the set of all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, for $\mathbb{R}^1$, there is only a single class of norms but for $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are infinitely many classes, specifically all $p$ norms live in different equivalence classes (except for the fact that the $1$-norm and the $\infty$-norm are equivalent). For general $\mathbb{R}^n$ the case is even "worse".

Is there some way to classify these equivalence classes?

Comment: I'm not sure that the case $n=2$ is much easier as you can always define a norm $\|x\|=\| \|x\|_1,\ldots,\|x\|_n\|_{\alpha}$ where $\|\cdot\|_i$ are norms on $\Bbb R^2$ and $\|\cdot \|_{\alpha}$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: You can also do $\|x\| = \sum_i c_i\|x\|_i$ for any norms, so there certainly are a few things that can be done, but perhaps we can classify that "a norm is given by combinations of $p$ norms under these operations", or something similar. Anothing thing we may classify is some set of "fundamental" norms, that cannot be derived from any other norms.

Comment: Note that the norm you mention is the special case where $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ is a weighted $1$ norm on $\Bbb R^n$. Anyway, don't get me wrong, although I believe what you are asking is a very difficult question, I think it is of high interest.

Comment: The question seems to be essentially to classify (balanced, bounded and absorbing) convex shapes in a linear space, which stated that way seems a bit hopeless.  On the other hand, there could be much interesting to say about the topology or some other structure (and remarkable points, etc.) of the space of all norms.

Comment: every norm is the pull back of  sup norm on $C[0,1]$ however  my comment is  not so  relevant to the  main question.

Comment: @Surb Maybe I misunderstood what you are saying, but in general the expression $\lVert \lVert\cdot\rVert_1, \ldots\rVert_{\alpha}$ is not a norm.

Comment: @gsa why not? (note that everything is *finite* in my expression)

Comment: @Surb If you try to prove the triangle inequality, it doesn't work. For a concrete counterexample consider the matrix $A = [4,-4;1,1]$ and the norm $\lVert x\rVert := \lvert Ax\rvert_2 = (16(x_1-x_2)^2 + (x_1+x_2)^2)^{1/2}$. Then $N(x) = \lVert \lvert x\rvert_1, \lvert x\rvert_\infty\rVert$ is not a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For $x=(1,0), y=(0,1)$ you get $N(x+y) = 5$ but $N(x) = N(y) = 2$.

Comment: @gsa you are right! I forgot to add that $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ should be an absolute norm.

Comment: What would you mean by an absolute norm in this setting?

Comment: @JonasAdler An absolute norm is a norm that satisfies $\|\, |x|\, \| = \|x\|$ for all $x$ where the absolute value is taken component wise. In particular, it can be shown that such norms satisfy $\|x\|\leq \|y\|$ for all $x,y$ such that $0\leq x_i\leq y_i$ (it is in fact an equivalence). So if $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ is absolute, for the triangle inequality we get $$\| \|x+y\|_1,\ldots,\|x+y\|_n\|_{\alpha}\leq\| \|x\|_1+\|y\|_1,\ldots,\|x\|_n+\|y\|_n\|_{\alpha}$$ $$\leq\| \|x\|_1,\ldots,\|x\|_n\|_{\alpha}+\| \|y\|_1,\ldots,\|y\|_n\|_{\alpha}$$ 
as desired.

Answer (score 6):

When $G={\bf GL}_n$, the set of classes of equivalent norms over ${\mathbb R}^n$ is a compact Hausdorff space when equipped with the Banach-Mazur metric
$$d(N_1,N_2)=\log\delta(N_1,N_2)$$
where 
$$\delta(N_1,N_2)=\inf_{T\in{\bf GL}_n}\|T^{-1}\|_{N_2\rightarrow N_1}\cdot\|T\|_{N_1\rightarrow N_2}\,.$$
See [this page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_compactum)

Of course, the smaller the group $G$, the bigger the set of equivalence classes.

Answer (score 4):

The following paper describes some invariants of the $GL(n)$ action.

-MR0190708 (32 #8120) 
Rutovitz, D.
Some parameters associated with finite-dimensional Banach spaces. 
J. London Math. Soc. 40 1965 241–255.